# difference between Class().property and self.class.property

Tags: python, class

The following code is my original attempt at getting a gui app to update its font etc,, when the user changed it in the config.ini settings:

```
def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
    """
    sets font,size colour etc..
    when user changes in settings.
    """
     if config is self.config:
    token = (section, key)
    if token == ('Font', 'button_font'):
        print('Our button font has  been changed to', value)
        GetInformation().lay_button.font_size = str(value)
        GetInformation().bet_button.font_size = str(value)


def build(self):
    self.config.write()
    return GetInformation()
```

My code updated the config but the screen never updated without restarting the app.

The following code  works:

```
def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
    """
    sets font,size colour etc..
    when user changes in settings.
    """

    if config is self.config:
        token = (section, key)
        if token == ('Font', 'button_font'):
            print('Our button font has  been changed to', value)
            self.getInformation.lay_button.font_size = str(value)
            self.getInformation.bet_button.font_size = str(value)


def build(self):
    self.config.write()
    self.getInformation = GetInformation()
    return self.getInformation
```

What is the difference between calling GetInformation().lay_button.font_size
and  self.getInformation.lay_button.font_size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you design your code specifically (typically a *Singleton* pattern), `Class().method()` creates a new object instantiated from `Class` and calls on it the method `method`. **The object is then destroyed** as there is no receiving variable specified.

`self.object.method()` on the other hand calls the method `method` on the existing object `self.object`. This object is persistent as it is saved as a member of your top level class (`self`).

In your first example, you are actually calling different methods on three different objects. In the method `on_config_change`, the two objects are immediately destroyed. In the second example, all the calls apply on the same object, that then keeps its modified properties.

Comment: Thanks, the confusing  bit that put me off was using self.getInformation before doing self.getInformation = GetInformation().

Comment: The order of execution of a statement is not relative to its place in the file in case of functions. This code only works of course when the function `build` is called before `on_config_change`. If it wasn't the case, you would end getting a `AttributeError` as `self.getInformation` wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `GetInformation().lay_button.font_size` changes the `lay_button`'s font size for a *brand new* `GetInformation` that you just created and didn't hook into anything.

Setting `self.getInformation.lay_button.font_size` changes the `lay_button`'s font size for the current `GetInformation` that `on_config_change` fired for. It's *that* `GetInformation` that's hooked into your system so it's that `GetInformation` you need to do your work on.